# Using 'unlike' in a negative sentence

Tags: meaning, prepositions

> Like you, I'm a great dancer.

You are a great dancer. I am a great dancer too.

> Unlike you, I'm not a great dancer.

You are a great dancer, but I am not.

***What does "Unlike you, I'm a great dancer." mean?***

> You are not a great dancer but I am.

*Right?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is nothing fancy.  "Like you, I..." means you and I have the same attribute.  "Unlike you, I..." mean that you and I have different attributes.  If "I'm a great dancer" and you are different, then you're not a great dancer.

It's a little rude to say that.